# Recursion with ternary operator 'hack' in Python

Tags: python, recursion, conditional-operator

Playing around in Python, I found that the following code works as I expected:

```
f = lambda S,b : (S if len(S)==b else f(S[1:],b))
```

From a list S, it will recursively drop the first element until the length of S equals b. For instance f([1,2,3,4,5,6],3) = [4,5,6].

However, much to my surprise the following solution, that uses the 'ternary hack' [a,b][c] instead of "b if c else a" (aka "c?b:a") does not work:

```
g = lambda S,b : (g(S[1:],b),S)[len(S)==b]
```

This will exceed maximum recursion depth.

Why doesn't this work?

(I know neither is an example of great coding style but that is beside the point now.)

Comment: In the second case, both elements of the tuple are computed, and then one of them is chosen. That means that the recursive call always happens!

Comment: Note that the function lacks a safeguard in case `len(S) < b`, i.e. it will recursively cut away from the list, even when its empty, leading to infinite recursive calls to `g`.

Comment: +1 Ternary hack is new to me :)

Comment: I just learned that interesting fact that the following code does work: `g = lambda S,b : (lambda : g(S[1:],b), lambda : S)[len(S)==b]()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, lets look at the `ast` the lambda function generates:

```
import ast
tree = ast.parse('lambda S,b : (g(S[1:],b),S)[len(S)==b]')
ast.dump(tree)
```

After some formatting done in vim this is what I got:

```
Module(
  [Expr(
    Lambda(
      arguments(
        [Name('S', Param()), Name('b', Param())],
        None,
        None,
        []
      ),
      Subscript(
        Tuple(
          [Call(
              Name('g', Load()),
              [Subscript(Name('S', Load()), Slice(Num(1), None, None), Load()), Name('b', Load())],
              [],
              None,
              None
            ),
            Name('S', Load())
          ],
          Load()
        ),
        Index(
          Compare(
            Call(Name('len', Load()), [Name('S', Load())], [], None, None),
            [Eq()],
            [Name('b', Load())]
          )
        ),
        Load()
      )
    )
  )]
)
```

As you may see, the first thing this code executes when calls the lambda is the tuple creation and after that, comes directly the recursive call (`Call(Name('g'...`) to the same lambda.

Calling is the first thing getting done and since the slicing of an empty list is still the empty list:

```
>>>[1][1:]
[]
>>>[][1:]
[]
```

This means that `g(S[1:])` will reduce your list until the empty list and then continue endlessly calling `g` with the empty list. This happens because the way the parser execute the statements. The first thing that's executed is the recursive method call, so it won't stop.

My point: base case is not working on the recursion.

Hope this bring more light to the subject.

Comment: Got three helpful answers and they're all appreciated; I accepted this one because the "ast" trick may be helpful for other strange encounters in python.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is related to how the ternary operator works. When you use a ternary operator, both expresions gets evaluated before checking the condition.

```
g = lambda S,b : (g(S[1:],b),S)[len(S)==b]
```

So in this case `g(S[1:],b)` gets evaluated before even reaching the if statement.

If you have a function, there's no base case which is the same case with `g(S[1:],b)`

```
def func(S, b)
    return func(S[1:],)

func(S,b)
#output: error - exceed maximum recursion depth
```

S[1:] will reach the point where it's empty and if it's empty, it will return an empty list.

A small example about the empty list:

```
S = [0, 1]

S = S[1:]
# [1]

S = S[1:]
# [] # empty

S = S[1:]
# [] # also empty
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do `A if C else B`, then `C` is executed first, and then *one of* `A` or `B` is executed (and it's result returned), whereas if you do `[B, A][C]`, both `A` and `B` are executed, *and then* `C`. You can easily check this by doing `p("A") if p("C") else p("B")` and `[p("B"), p("A")][p("C")]` with some function `p` that prints its input and then returns `True` or `False`

So in your first case, `S if len(S)==b else f(S[1:],b)`, the recursive call is executed only if the condition does not apply. In the second case, however, it is executed *before the condition is even tested*, and the same in the recursively called function, ad infinitum.

(I assume that you do not intend to use this in practice, so this may not be important, but anyhow: note that (1) both functions lack a safeguard for the case `len(S) < b`, (2) the same can be achieved with `S[-b:]`, and (3) using `if/else` is, of course, *much* more readable.)

Comment: The actual use that I had in mind was a challenge that I set for myself to code a certain algorithm in one single statement. The algorithm includes nested while-if constructions. So I thought of recursion combined with ternary operators as my way out :-)